# PL SQL : NVL first parameter type conversion issue

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I have a table Application which has a column

```
BORROWINGTERM   NUMBER(10,0) Nullable
```

why this script throw an error (ORA-01722 invalid number)

```
select nvl(borrowingterm, 'no term') from Application
```

while this one works

```
select nvl(to_char(borrowingterm), 'no term') from Application
```

and this one also works

```
select nvl(1234,5678) from dual;
```

base on [this article](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php)

the first parameter of NVL function should be string type

Comment: That article, while ok, is not completely accurate. NVL is overloaded for a number of data types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting the error because you are mixing two different types in the nvl clause.  One number, one string.  The types must be the same.

Answer (score 6):

Keeping it simple ,

- String null can be replaced with string Substitute value.
- Number null can be replaced by number value and so on..

Example:

```
select nvl(to_char(borrowingterm), 'no term') from Application;
```

`//conert number to string and then provide string substitute value to column`

```
select nvl(borrowingterm, 0') from Application;
```

`// replacing null with 0`

Answer (score 5):

In short, if the first argument is numeric then Oracle attempts to convert the second argument to a number.

See NVL documentation

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm#i91798

Answer (score 5):

In your first example, because `borrowingterm` is a numeric type, Oracle is trying to implicitly convert the string 'no term' to a numeric, hence the error.

See the [NVL documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm#i91798).

Answer (score 2):

> "the first parameter of NVL function
>   should be string type"

I think you gave the answer yourself. If you are asking why, you should consider the possibility of reusing the output type of NVL in another function.

```
select to_date(nvl(number_field, 'some_text')) from dual
```

In the situation above, the output of nvl is unknown, thus an ORA-01722 is raised.